# get rid of empty panels in the first row of facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I was trying to use `facet_grid` to lay out panels, for example,

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
economics %>%
  filter(date >= ymd(19680101)) %>% 
  mutate(
    year = year(date),
    month = month(date),
    decade = floor(year/10) * 10,
    single = year - decade,
    decade = paste0(decade, "s")
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(month, uempmed)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(decade ~ single)
```

[image]

My question is, how can I get ride of the first 7 panels (and the last 4), leaving them **totally blank**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found this easiest to do by editing the panel grobs in a `gtable` before plotting.

First lets save the ggplot object in `myplot`

```
myplot <- economics %>%
  filter(date >= ymd(19680101)) %>% 
  mutate(
    year = year(date),
    month = month(date),
    decade = floor(year/10) * 10,
    single = year - decade,
    decade = paste0(decade, "s")
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(month, uempmed)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(decade ~ single)
```

Now we can remove the panels before plotting.  I demonstrate using `cowplot::plot_to_gtable`, although there are also several other packages that provide functions to convert a ggplot into a gtable.

```
library(cowplot)
library(grid)
gt <- plot_to_gtable(myplot)
to.delete = which (gt$layout$t == 8 & gt$layout$r <= 19 & grepl('panel', gt$layout$name))
to.delete = c(to.delete, which(gt$layout$t == 18 & gt$layout$r >= 17 & grepl('panel', gt$layout$name)))

gt$grobs[to.delete] <- NULL
gt$layout <- gt$layout[-to.delete, ]
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

We can also move up the axes for the empty cells like this:

```
to.move = which(gt$layout$r >= 17 & grepl('axis-b', gt$layout$name))
gt$layout$t[to.move] <- gt$layout$t[to.move] - 2
gt$layout$b[to.move] <- gt$layout$b[to.move] - 2
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution. Is it possible to get ride of (or move up) the x coordinates of the last 4 panels? Thanks.

Comment: added this to answer

Answer (score 0):

With the current development version of `ggplot2` (see below *), the names of the panel `grobs` in the `gtable` are corrected to `'panel-[row]-[col]'`.

This allows to use `gtable_filter()` to manually remove certain panels by their names (e.g. `'panel-6-8'`) in a straightforward way:

```
# remotes::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

myplot <- economics %>%
  filter(date >= ymd(19680101)) %>% 
  mutate(year = year(date),
         month = month(date),
         decade = floor(year/10) * 10,
         single = year - decade,
         decade = paste0(decade, "s")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(month, uempmed)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(decade ~ single)

myplot %>%
  # Generate gtable of ggplot object
  ggplot2::ggplot_build() %>% ggplot2::ggplot_gtable() %>%
  # Modify gtable by filtering out grobs based on name using a regex pattern
  # $ represents end of string. Otherwise 'panel-1-1' removes 'panel-1-10', too.
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-1-1$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-1-2$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-1-3$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-1-4$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-1-5$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-1-6$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-1-7$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-1-8$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-6-7$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-6-8$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-6-9$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-6-10$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  # Plot the modified gtable
  {grid::grid.newpage(); grid::grid.draw(.)}
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

To identify panel names I use the following snippet:

```
# Plot panel-names
# Extract  panels from the gtable layout (incl. their names and positions)
gtable_panel_positions <- myplot %>% 
  ggplotGrob() %>%
  magrittr::extract2("layout") %>%
  filter(grepl("panel-",name))

# Generate grobs with labels
grobs_to_add <- 
  sprintf("name: '%s'\ngtable index: [%d,%d]",
        gtable_panel_positions$name,
        gtable_panel_positions$t,
        gtable_panel_positions$l) %>%
  lapply(grid::textGrob, gp=grid::gpar(fontsize=5))

# Add grobs with labels and plot
myplot %>% 
  ggplotGrob() %>%
  gtable::gtable_add_grob(grobs = grobs_to_add,
                          t=gtable_panel_positions$t, 
                          l=gtable_panel_positions$l) %>%
  {grid::grid.newpage(); grid::grid.draw(.)}
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You can get the newest development version of `ggplot2`* with `remotes::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")`.

* ggplot2 version as of 2020-05-01, commit: `#e0f1040c1217585b22111b2ed11cd967320dcccd`